# What are the secured template engines in Java?

Tags: java, django, templates, template-engine, jinja2

I'm looking for a template engine in Java that disallow code execution in template, only tags.

In a perfect world, I would be searching for an equivalent to [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/) (or the [Django template engine](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/)).
Based on Django, template tags will be used when created by me, but a user can't create a template tag (by executing code).

I would implement it in the [Play! Framework](http://www.playframework.org/).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think freemarker is a template engine for java (Syntax not like Django) but it provides the View Separation principles in the MVC world : http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_quickstart_basics.html

Comment: In Django's template engine, you can write your own tags, effectively allowing arbitrary code execution (provided it is written in a custom tag).  Is this expected, or should it be limited to a set of built-in tags?

Comment: Freemarker allows code in the templates, and is bad advice for these requirements.

Comment: @André Caron : I answered your question :) (I think).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suggestions for a Java-based templating engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174204/suggestions-for-a-java-based-templating-engine)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) is what you are looking for.

> Its distinguishing characteristic is
>   that it [strictly enforces model-view
>   separation](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~parrt/papers/mvc.templates.pdf) unlike other engines.
>   Strict separation makes websites and
>   code generators more flexible and
>   maintainable; **it also provides an
>   excellent defense against malicious
>   template authors**

Comment: There's such a thing as _malicious template authors_?  Who lets arbitrary users write templates?

Comment: Think `SQL` injection attack vector but with templates instead of `SQL`. Any web site that generates pages with a template system that lets you include executable code instructions in the template is susceptible to malicious intent.

Comment: Websites like Tumblr, Posterous, allow user to change the template. Then, everyone can be a "malicious template author" :)

Answer (score 1):

From your requirements, it looks as if all you required was a template engine that didn't allow anything similar to JSP's scriptlets (between <% and %>) and was only based in tags and/or attributes...

If so, I'd like to suggest you Thymeleaf http://www.thymeleaf.org (here a [comparison with JSP](http://www.thymeleaf.org/thvsjsp.html)), of which I'm the author. But if I'm not wrong these are requirements that could also be fulfilled by Velocity http://velocity.apache.org, so its up to yo to choose!

Comment: Thymeleaf is cumbersome and very hard to get used to because of the way it embeds itself with markup. Plus no OOB inheritance. You have to use macros, then call the macros which is counterintuitive.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to provide a simple way to modify they templates without much learning about hundreds of custom tags and achieve a clearly defined functionality to be accessed, while being free how to present it, you should think about passive templates. This ensures, no malicious code can be added:) A strong engine with passive templates in java is [Snippetory](http://www.jproggy.org/snippetory/). However if you want to control access, access control might be a good idea, too.